# Unable to set default gateway from python

Tags: python, gateway, ioctl

I have written code to set default gateway using `ioctl` in C. I have a function to set the gateway and the usual main function. When I compile and run the code it works fine, but when I turn it into a library and call the main function from python using `ctypes` the `ioctl` call fails. Why is this?

Note: Before using `ctypes` method, I tried to set gateway from python using `fcntl`, `ioctl` and `socket` but it failed with `OSError` saying `invalid arguments`.

## gateway.c

```
int setDefaultGW( int sockfd, char* gatewatStr)
{

    struct sockaddr_in *dst, *gw, *mask;
    struct rtentry route;
    in_addr_t gip;

    fprintf( stderr,"socket %d\n", sockfd);
    fprintf( stderr,"Address %s\n", gatewatStr);
    gip = inet_addr(gatewatStr);
    fprintf( stderr,"Address %d\n", gip);

memset(&route,0,sizeof(struct rtentry));

dst = (struct sockaddr_in *)(&(route.rt_dst));
gw = (struct sockaddr_in *)(&(route.rt_gateway));
mask = (struct sockaddr_in *)(&(route.rt_genmask));

/* Make sure we're talking about IP here */
dst->sin_family = AF_INET;
gw->sin_family = AF_INET;
mask->sin_family = AF_INET;

/* Set up the data for adding the default route */
dst->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
gw->sin_addr.s_addr = gip;
mask->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
route.rt_metric = 100;
route.rt_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;

/* Remove this route if it already exists */
ioctl(sockfd,SIOCDELRT,&route);

/* Add the default route */
if( ioctl(sockfd,SIOCADDRT,&route) < 0 )
{
    fprintf( stderr,"Adding default route: %d\n", errno);
    return -1;
}

fprintf( stdout,"Added default route successfully.\n" );
return 0;
}

int main(){

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
    {
        perror("socket creation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    setDefaultGW(sockfd, "192.168.6.1");
    return 0;
}
```

## net.py

```
gatewayFun = ctypes.CDLL("./libgateway.so") 
gatewayFun.main()
```

Running the C binary:

```
./gateway                                                                                                               
socket 3
Address 192.168.6.1
Address 17213632
Added default route successfully.
```

Running the python script:

```
# python3 net.py 
socket 4
Address 192.168.6.1
Address 17213632
Adding default route: 101
```

Comment: I'm pulling this out of the ether, but could you make sure that python has permissions to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Nullman Thanks for the reply. I am not sure if it is a permission error since I was able to set IP address and netmask from python using ioctl calls.